# JQuery to css write nth-child()

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I need to make a slider for school. 
I know that I can use something like

```
.sliders img:nth-child(Index) {}
```

I know it need to be like

```
 $(".sliders img").css.........
```

My question is how to write Child Index value into nth-child using Jquery?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to your project, but please be aware of the (limited) cross-browser compatibility of nth-child. For example, it won't work on IEXPL versions < 9.0
You may want to test, and see in how far lack of support breaks your design.

Answer (score 2):

You use string concatenation:

```
$(".sliders img:nth-child(" + index + ")").css.......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.eq()` to avoid ugly string concatenation.

```
$(".sliders img").eq(index - 1).css();
```

Comment: That won't work. It gives you the image at the given index from the entire collection instead of all images within each `.sliders` that are the `nth-child` of their respective parent.

Comment: To do it without concatenation, you'll need to iterate over all `.slider img` elements, and check the `.index()` of each one (relative to their siblings) to see if it matches the desired index. That'll be far more ugly and slow compared to the concatenation.

Comment: I might not be following right. Can you give me an example? Here is what I've been messing around with: http://jsbin.com/daherujuju/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple `sliders` elements, they should each have all `img` elements that are the second child of the image's parent selected. Here's your demo with 3 `slider` elements. http://jsbin.com/yenajegigi/1/edit

Comment: Ah. I assumed a lot about the markup. Though, if they're trying to create more than one slider in one call they're in for a headache.